# How to implement a belongs_to with by_group in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am wondering how to set up the models in my rails application.  I know I need to use some sort of nested association but not sure what the proper specification should be.  Description of the problem can be found below, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I work for a private equity firm that owns many different companies.  We want to build an web application to track purchasing across the portfolio.  More specifically, we want to understand how much we are spending with specific vendors and with specific categories of vendors, both in aggregate and at each company.

Modeling this would seem straightforward enough.  You create a companies model, a categories model, a vendors model (where each vendor belongs to a category), and a transactions model (where each transaction belongs to a specific vendor and a specific company).  However, there is a wrinkle in the requirements that I am not sure how to handle.   We want to allow different companies to classify the same vendor differently, but also have a standard classification for each vendor.  So one company could  classify staples as office equipment, another might classify them as SGA-office supplies but we would maintain a standard classification that always mapped staples to office supplies.

What is the best way to set this up?  I was thinking I would create 2 category models, one called stanard_category with :has_many => vendors.  Another called company_category with :has_many => vendors by company.  Is this the right approach? If so, how do I specify that the :has_many relationship  on company_category is specific to each company?  Is this a situation where I would want to use nested routes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example structure that would suit your needs:

```
class Company
  has_many   :company_categories
end

class CompanyCategory
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vendors
end

class StandardCategory
  has_many   :vendors
end

class Vendor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_categories
  belongs_to :standard_category
end
```

Whether or not you'd use nested routes depends on the specifics of your application.